# Usage of cookie in POSTMAN

Tags: php, postman, burp

I am trying to login to a website using postman. 
The website is done using PHP and  I have the username and the password for it.

I installed burp to check what are we posting in order to login, and it shows the following:

[image]

However, when I add the 3 of the parameters with their correct values in POSTMAN the site does not login, and I get the login page again, which means there is something wrong with the info I am sending.

I suspect this is the cookie, but how can I send a cookie with the Header's parameters in POSTMAN?

Although the same cookie appears below in the cookies section in POSTMAN as below.

[image]

### EDIT 1:

The reason I am posting this is because I want to save to a CSV format the contents of a webpage by creating a PHP script that will go through the pages that are in this format `http://example.com/page.php?id=151` and `http://example.com/page.php?id=152` and so forth.

However, as mentioned my problem is the authentication where I can't seem to bypass the login page even though I have the username and the password. 
At the moment, I am trying this using postman, to see if it is possible, because if it so, I will try to code it in PHP, but It is not working.

Comment: did you try to include ``Cookie:name=value``? so in Request Header in postman, create a Header with key ``Cookie`` and value ``name=value``

Comment: Have you tried adding this in the `Manage Cookies` feature? You'll find the `Cookies` option under the `Save` button

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the following:

1. Run the request in your browser, open Dev Tools, copy the request as curl and import it in Postman. See a video on how to do it: https://youtu.be/lqqYBLJR1Yc
2. It is possible that the form you are submitting includes other values as well, such as a CSRF token, which is generated with each page load. If this is the case, things get more complicated - just let me know how it worked out.

Comment: I watched the video and tried the recommended, however the XHR tab is empty after I make the request.

Comment: Valentin Despa, I edited the question and added an EDIT1 , have a look, and you might have a different idea.

Comment: @tony9099 Try the Document, instead of XHR. Depends on your request.